# How to receive messages from server using socket io

Tags: android, socket.io

i am making an android application using  Socket.IO-Client for Java written by Gottox.i know how to send messages to the server but i want to know how to receive message or get response from the server 
here it is a sample of my code

```
 SocketIO socket=new SocketIO();
        try {
            socket = new SocketIO("http://41.69.21.123:1333/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                try {
                    tv.setText(json.toString(2));
                    System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
            }

            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                System.out.println("an Error occured");
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            public void onDisconnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
            }

            public void onConnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection established");
            }

            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
            }
        });


        socket.send("Hello Server!");


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I receiving message at this method

```
  @Override
        public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
            System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
            //it comes with 3 parameters event, acknowledge and args
            //if you want to get args to String try this
              Object[] arguments = args;
            System.out.println("Args"+ arguments[0].toString());
        }
```

you can check server response at log with socket.io tags

Comment: How do you exactly receive messages inside public void on()? Mine doesn't get called at all.

Answer (score 0):

The method onMessage in IOCallback can get message Server sended by the parameter "String data"
If this method never tiggered by the message server send, maybe your connection is not alive